# NSNumber double with many decimal places being rounded/truncated

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber

I have a `double` in an `NSNumber`.

```
double myDouble = 1363395572.6129999;

NSNumber *doubleNumber = @(myDouble); 
// using [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble] leads to the same result
```

This is where it gets problematic.

`doubleNumber.doubleValue` seems to return the correct and full value `(1363395572.6129999)`

However, looking at `doubleNumber` in the debugger or doing `doubleNumber.description` gives me `(1363395572.613)`.

I would understand if perhaps this was just some display formatting, but when I then stick this object into a JSON payload, the messed up rounded value gets inserted instead of the actual number.

The way I'm doing this is something like this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:(Dictionary containing NSNumber)
                                                           options:0 error:nil];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Looking at the string at this point shows me the truncated number with 3 decimal places even though the `NSNumber` I inserted had 7.

My question is why is this happening and more importantly how can I stop it from happening?

**EDIT with conclusion:**

For anyone who stumbles onto this, the problem was not clear to me from the beginning but the actual issue is that `NSNumber` and `double` are both incapable of holding a number with the sort of precision I am looking for. As Martin's answer shows, my problem occurred as soon as I deserialized the initial number values from a JSON response.

I ended up working around my problem by reworking the whole system to stop depending on this level of precision(since these are timestamps, microseconds) of these numbers on the client, and instead use a different identifier to pass around with the API.

As Martin and Leo pointed out, in order to get around this problem one would need to use a custom JSON parser that allows parsing of a JSON number into an `NSDecimalNumber` rather than an `NSNumber`. A better solution to my problem in particular was what I outlined in the previous paragraph, so I did not pursue this route.

Comment: 1363395572.6129999 _is_ 1363395572.613

Comment: A `double` can only store about 13 significant digits.

Comment: `description` is only to be used for debugging, and should never (except for a handful of object types) be counted on to accurately reflect the contents of the object.

Comment: @HotLicks yeah I'm not using it for anything other than debugging, I was just listing out everything I've tried.

Comment: @rmaddy - A `double` can hold nearly 16 significant decimal digits.

Comment: @rmaddy I should add that the plain `double` shows the correct value at all times and never appears truncated. I can pass it around and use the full value in its primitive form without any issues.

Comment: Hmmm. I would have sworn `double` was about 13 digits. Maybe that idea came about from seeing the same behavior seen here.

Comment: @rmaddy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: Try using `NSNumber *doubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble];` and see if it makes a difference. I've seen the `@()` notation causing issues by selecting the incorrect internal `NSNumber` subclass.

Comment: Don't use the `@` notation, create the NSNumber the "old fashioned" way.

Comment: @LeoNatan same result. Once again the `NSNumber` is actually storing the correct value. I see that it is a `double` in the debugger and when I print `doubleValue` it is indeed correct.

Comment: @HotLicks no difference in the result unfortunately. going to edit my question to note that.

Comment: One obvious thing to try is to make a [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f", myDouble] and see what it looks like. If you can force what you want that way before putting it into JSON, that should solve things. {EDIT: posted as answer, tested and works]

Comment: @RobP - Except that's putting a string rather than a number into the JSON.

Comment: Who is generating your JSON, by the way?  Do you do that, or is it some 3rd party?  Where is the JSON coming from?

Comment: @HotLicks I do, no third party.

Comment: How are you generating the floating-point number in the JSON, then?  Does it originate as a `double`?  If so, then it only has about 15.8 digits of precision, and you're expecting 17.  If you want exact, don't use a float, but use a scaled long.  (But of course if you're starting with an NSTimeInterval, double precision is all you get.)

Comment: I believe it is a Time object generated with Ruby. The server side precision was not the issue as it maintains microsecond precision. I did end up realizing that NSTimeInterval was not suitable for maintaining that precision however and went another route (as outlined in my edited question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already said in above comments, the precision of `double` is about 16 decimal
digits. `1363395572.612999` has 17 digits, and converting this decimal number
to `double` gives exactly the same results as for `1363395572.613`:

```
double myDouble = 1363395572.6129999;
double myDouble1 = 1363395572.613;

NSLog(@"%.20f", myDouble);  // 1363395572.61299991607666015625
NSLog(@"%.20f", myDouble1); // 1363395572.61299991607666015625
NSLog(@"%s", myDouble == myDouble1 ? "equal" : "different"); // equal
```

Therefore, within the precision of `double`, the output `1363395572.613`
is **correct**.

If your goal is to send precisely the number "1363395572.6129999" then you cannot 
store it in a `double` first because that already looses the precision.
A possible solution would be to use `NSDecimalNumber` (which has a precision
of 38 decimal digits):

```
NSDecimalNumber *doubleNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1363395572.6129999"];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key": doubleNumber};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// {"key":1363395572.6129999}
```

Example with `long double` and `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
long double ld1 = 1363395572.6129999L;
long double ld2 = 1363395572.613L;

NSDecimalNumber *num1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7Lf", ld1]];
NSDecimalNumber *num2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7Lf", ld2]];

NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key1": num1, @"key2": num2};
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// {"key1":1363395572.6129999,"key2":1363395572.613}
```

*Update:* As it turned out in the discussion, the problem occurs already when the data
is read from a JSON object sent by a server. The following example shows that 
`NSJSONSerialization` is not able to read floating point numbers with more than
"double" precision from JSON data:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"key1\":1363395572.6129999,\"key2\":1363395572.613}";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];
NSNumber *n1 = dict2[@"key1"];
NSNumber *n2 = dict2[@"key2"];

BOOL b = [n1 isEqualTo:n2]; // YES
```

Comment: The problem here is that doing `double myDouble = 1363395572.613;` generates the same result, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. These numbers are microsecond precision timestamps and those 2 numbers do not represent the same time when comparing at that level.

Comment: @Dima:  `1363395572.6129999` and `1363395572.613`, when stored in a `double`, are exactly identical! - If you have to distinguish these values, you cannot use `double`. Use `NSDecimalNumber` or (perhaps) `long double`.

Comment: @Dima: I have updated the answer with an example that show that your problem occurs already when reading the server JSON.

Comment: Question:  Are you sure the value that NSJSONSerialization produced is a double and not a LongDecimal?

Comment: @HotLicks: The class of n1/n2 is __NSCFNumber, and the objCType is "d". And both numbers compare as equal. (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html also mentions that Objective-C does not support "long double".)

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSDecimalNumber`:

```
NSDecimalNumber* dc = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f", myDouble]];
```

Use this decimal number inside your dictionary.

---

If you have a string value of the required number precisely, feed that directly to the `NSDecimalNumber` constructor to get a precise decimal number. Do not use an intermediate `double` stage, where you lose precision.

Comment: And for `double myDouble = 1363395572.613` this gives also `1363395572.6129999` ...

Comment: @MartinR I guess precision has to be known? If more precision is necessary, what about `long double`?

Comment: My point is: There is **no difference** between `double myDouble = 1363395572.6129999;` and `double myDouble = 1363395572.613`. Therefore "1363395572.613" in the JSON data is fine and not an error.

Comment: @MartinR So the error is in the use of `double`. Precision here matters, so matt's comment that "1363395572.6129999 is 1363395572.613" may be technically correct for "double", it is incorrect in the term of the asker's requirements.

Comment: Yes. If the goal is to send the value stored in `double myDouble` then the result "1363395572.613" is "correct". If the goal is to send the number "1363395572.6129999" then you cannot store it in `double` first.

Comment: The problem here is that doing `double myDouble = 1363395572.613;` generates the same result, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. These numbers are microsecond precision timestamps and those 2 numbers do not represent the same time when comparing at that level.

Comment: @Dima How do you generate the double?

Comment: Actually you can make your method work by using "long double" consequently: `long double ld1 = 1363395572.6129999l; NSDecimalNumber *num = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7Lf", ld1]];` .

Comment: @MartinR just tried that and it doesn't work. Both of my resulting decimal numbers are `1363395572.6129999` even though one of the long doubles is `1363395572.613`.

Comment: @Dima: I have updated my answer with an example that show how it works with long double. The important point is that you have to use "long double" consequently, such as `1363395572.6129999L` with the `L` suffix for a "long double constant".

Comment: @LeoNatan the number is generated by a server as a timestamp and sent over to the client as a JSON number. Then at some later point I am supposed to send it back to the API and the number should be the same.

Comment: @Dima: In that case I assume that the problem occurs already when *reading* the JSON data from the server. "1363395572.6129999" in the JSON data is converted to a NSNumber object containing a double. "1363395572.613" would be converted to exactly the same number.

Comment: @Dima If you are receiving a string value of the number, feed that directly into a `NSDecimalValue` instead of going through a `double` step and losing precision.

Comment: @MartinR so I guess the question then is what the best way would be to extract that JSON number and maintain precision.

Comment: @LeoNatan I don't actually need or have a string at any point, it is passed to me as a number.

Comment: @Dima "JSON number" has come to you as string, no? (In the form of a JSON data stream.) I understand the deserializer parses it to a `NSNumber`, but you can parse it yourself to get a string value.

Comment: @Dima: As far as I can see, `NSJSONSerialization` is not able to parse your number with the full precision, it uses NSNumber with doubles. Perhaps there are alternative JSON parsers with more precision (or you parse it yourself, as Leo suggested).

Comment: JSON format has a very defined structure, so if necessary, it is not difficult to create a custom parser. You could find an open-source one and change it for your needs.

Comment: Yeah guys, it looks like this is beyond the scope of what the default serialization does. For what it's worth I have decided to use a different variable altogether for this particular API call which allows me to avoid having to send over these timestamps and having to deal with building my own serializer

Answer (score 1):

I just tried and it does seem that the precision is being lost in serialization, not in initialization of the number.  Maybe JSON serialization is building a string with precision-losing number formatting, then building data from that.

One solution would be to save the integral and fractional values in their own 8 byte fields... maybe use two LP64 longs.  The precision part can be multiplied by something big, then divided upon retrieval.

Comment: The precision is already lost when you assign the value to a `double`.

Comment: @MartinR - True.  The original value is 17 digits, and `double` doesn't quite handle 16.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following code:

```
double myDouble = 1363395572.6129999;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f", myDouble];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Output is:

1363395572.6129999

So just format the string yourself before putting into JSON object and you should be fine.

EDIT:
If you want more precision, not just more control over what goes into the JSON, a `long double` will store it. Thus:

```
long double myDouble = 1363395572.6129999;
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7L", myDouble];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Comment: And for `double myDouble = 1363395572.613` you get the same output `1363395572.6129999`. So this does not "increase" the precision.

Comment: Yup, good point, but at least this point you aren't subject to the mysteries of what NSJSONSerialization does. I did just verify that even with type `long double` (at least on a 64-bit architecture) that `1363395572.613 == 1363395572.6129999` evaluates to true. So this is all just a 'what format do you want it in' game because the underlying *value* is the same.

Comment: ...which I just upvoted! I still think it's not a bad idea to format the string in one's one code if you have specific ideas in mind about the JSON you want. But if the issue is underlying *precision* then yes, changing type of storage for the value is required!

Comment: Note that that's an NSString, not an NSNumber.  There is a significant difference.

Comment: Sure there's a difference, but depending where the JSON is going it's not necessarily bad.

Comment: The problem here is that doing `double myDouble = 1363395572.613;` generates the same result, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. These numbers are microsecond precision timestamps and those 2 numbers  do not represent the same time when comparing at that level.

Comment: then you need higher precision storage, and Martin's answer is the way to go!

Comment: Actually you can make your method work by using "long double" consequently: `long double ld1 = 1363395572.6129999l;  NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7Lf", ld1];` .

Comment: @Dima - One should question whether the server should be transmitting time values as decimal fractions vs a scaled decimal integer (which would represent as `long` or "BigDecimal").  Any time you get a numeric value in JSON that's larger than the common 64-bit `double` and `long` representations you're apt to get into trouble.