# JSONObjectWithData wrong decimal places while parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

In one of my api I am getting below response form server (If convert data into string)

```
{"success":true,"order_id":102232,"Total":68.6,"delivery_time":"7:30PM-10:00PM","delivery_date":"2016-03-25"}
```

But when I used the same with

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:self.readingOptions error:&serializationError];
```

Its return

```
{
Total = "68.59999999999999";
"delivery_date" = "2016-03-25";
"delivery_time" = "7:30PM-10:00PM";
"order_id" = 102232;
success = 1;
```

}

Due to multiple places after decimal in total field its creating problem in calculation.

I think the JSON serialization method converting it internally but don't know how to resolve this

Comment: Which one are you passing for reading option?

Comment: sometime float is not enough precise when typecasting values. it wont hurt your program until you need exact value. when you round of things , you will get what you want here.

Comment: I can't round off because I need to send it back to server and it will get validated there so single precision can distort the feature

Comment: Please read through http://floating-point-gui.de/, this is a completely correct behavior. Just use a `NSNumberFormatter` when you will be presenting the number to users.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019338/nsnumber-double-with-many-decimal-places-being-rounded-truncated
refer this

Comment: Any solution? XCode shouldn't change number with 1 decimal point into infinite decimal point ..

Answer (score 7):

@gnasher hinted at the issue, but didn't explain it in detail.

Computers use binary floating point to represent floating point numbers internally.

A floating point number is usually stored as either a float or a double. On most 64 bit platforms a float is stored in 4 bytes and a double is stored in 8 bytes.

Binary floating point can't represent many decimal values exactly. Internally, 68.6 is represented in binary as a value that works out to 68.59999999999999 in decimal. That is the closest that a computer can get to 68.6 when saving your value as a float.

Binary floating point values like floats and doubles do not have a "number of decimal places." The value gets converted to decimal for display, or for conversion to a string, and there is **always** the potential for rounding errors in that conversion.

Take this code for example:

```
float aFloat = 68.6;
NSLog(@"aFloat = %f", aFloat);
```

That displays:

```
aFloat = 68.599998
```

However, this code:

```
NSLog(@"aFloat (1 decimal place)= %.1f", aFloat);
```

Displays:

```
aFloat (1 decimal place)= 68.6
```

The JSON string you are parsing has numbers in it that are not in quotes. When you convert your JSON string to a Cocoa object, the value of "Total" gets saved as an NSNumber object, probably using a double type internally.

If you need to do math on your "Total" value then you need it to be a number.

If you want to avoid decimal conversion errors, change your server code to send the value "Total" as a string, (in quotes) not a numeric value. Then the `JSONObjectWithData` function will keep it as a string, `"68.6"`

In that case your JSON string would look like this:

```
{"success":true,"order_id":102232,"Total":"68.6","delivery_time":"7:30PM-10:00PM","delivery_date":"2016-03-25"}
```

You said "Due to multiple places after decimal in total field its creating problem in calculation." What problem? On the iOS side, or the server side?

Comment: It's actually a big problem on iOS that JSON parsers convert all numbers to `NSNumber` (with double precision) even the ones that we would like to keep as `NSDecimalNumber`. Alternative parsers (e.g. `SBJson`) have the same problem. The once time I wanted to parse correctly, I had to fork a parser and fix the behavior.

Comment: Sounds like Apple needs to enhance NSJSONSerialization to add an option that will create NSDecimalNumber objects for decimal values contained in the JSON string. Did you publish your custom `JSON` parser?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, that would be the correct solution. The same with `NSNumberFormatter` which also converts `NSDecimalNumber` to `double` (also fixable only by proprietary formatter). Unfortunately, my updated parser could not be published (company code). It was a fork of one of the first versions of `SBJson`, the fix was pretty trivial actually. (by the way, javascript parser has the same problem, also converting to double precision).

Comment: I'm not sure it is a "big problem" in the sense that 99.99% of consumers of `NSJSONSerialization` are going to want ordinary C primitive numbers, and the others aren't necessarily going to be satisfied by an `NSDecimalNumber`. `NSDecimalNumber` is a 64-bit floating point quantity, exactly like `double`, it just happens to have a base-10 exponent rather than a base 2. If you wanted to "parse correctly" you'd need a variable-sized numeric storage container. There are infinitely many numbers that I can encode in JSON that cannot be stored as an `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: @Tommy, NSDecimalNumber uses an NSDecimal structure internally, which has 8 `UInt16`s for the mantissa. It is capable of doing math on decimal quantities with 38 significant digits. The limit of a double is about 14 significant digits. It can represent larger values, greater precision, and avoid decimal rounding issues that you get when using doubles. it is not "a 64-bit floating point quantity, exactly like double".

Comment: You're right, my arithmetic was askew on the number of binary digits necessary to hold 38 decimal digits. Regardless, it's absurd to argue that "n bits of information in base 2 is incorrect, m > n bits of information in base 10 is **the correct solution**".

Comment: @Tommy, JSON sends numbers as strings of decimal digits. Going back and forth between JSON and native data formats forces a conversion between binary and decimal representation of numbers, with a potential for rounding errors. Offering the option to use NSDecimalNumber would be a good solution that would preserve the decimal value of numbers.

Comment: I agree it would be a good solution, I disagree with the unchallenged agreement that using `NSDecimalNumber` would be "**correct**" and that not using `NSDecimalNumber` constitutes "**a big problem**". It's a negligible problem and either a correct parser either may approximate numbers or may not. `NSDecimalNumber` approximates, e.g. as soon as I type a 39-digit number. (and I've just +1d your comment as I agree with "a good solution")

Comment: You could make the argument that `NSDecimalNumber` would be a better fit overall for JSON conversions than a double. `NSDecimalNumber` has greater range and greater precision than a double, and avoids binary/decimal conversion rounding errors. The arguments against it are data size and performance. `NSDecimalNumber` objects take more memory, and doing math with them is a lot slower than using binary floating point formats.

Answer (score 1):

This resolved my problem

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setPositiveFormat:@"0.##"];
NSLog(@"%@", [fmt stringFromNumber:dataDict[@"Total"]]);
```

Output of this log is **68.6**

Answer (score 0):

**Swift** Got the same issue while parsing, backend team was sending decimal. Just covert it to Float.

```
let value = Float(48.9999999999)
print(value) // 49.0

let value = Float(48.9799999999)
print(value) // 48.98
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using floating point arithmetic. What you are seeing is absolutely normal. You would have the exact same thing happening if you just assigned 68.6.

How do you resolve this? By learning about floating point arithmetic. But what problems do you actually see? Are you just panicking because you see loads of nines, or is there an actual problem?

What makes you actually think that converting the data back to JSON will produce something that the server misunderstands? Have you tried it? Are you worrying about a theoretical possibility, or do you have actual evidence of a problem? Clearly the server stored something rounded to one decimal.

I mean seriously do you get that what you are worrying about is the output of an NSLog statement?

Comment: The problem is its converting .6 into .599999999 which is getting failed when I send the value back to server because now the value which I have is .59999 instead of .6

Comment: @iOSRocks In that case the problem is on your server. There are ways to remedy that, e.g. using `NSDecimalNumber` to hold numbers, with a custom JSON parser and encoder, but it's much easier to fix the server.

Comment: same thing is working fine with Android so we can't change the server side code